# Purpose of dereferencing a pointer as a parameter in C

Tags: c, pointers, indirection

I recently came along this line of code:

```
CustomData_em_free_block(&em->vdata, &eve->data);
```

And I thought, isn't:

```
a->b
```

just syntactic sugar for:

```
(*a).b
```

With that in mind, this line could be re-written as:

```
CustomData_em_free_block(&(*em).vdata, &(*eve).data);
```

If that's the case, what is the point of passing in

&(*a), as a parameter, and not just a?  It seems like the pointer equivalent of -(-a) is being passed in in, is there any logic for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
&(*em).vdata
```

is not the same as this:

```
em.vdata
```

It is the same as this:

```
&((*em).vdata)
```

The ampersand takes the address of `vdata`, which is a member of the struct pointed to by `em`.  The `.` operator has higher precedence than the `&` operator.

Comment: I agree with the unicorn part.  Anyway, that makes sense.  So in that case:

(&(*a)).b

is the same as:

a.b, but without the extra () in there to change the order of operations, the dot product happens first, right?

Thank you.

Comment: @Leif Andersen: Yes, `(&(*a)) == a`; that's the meaning of those two operators. And yes, the `.` has higher precedence than the `&`. It's not a dot product, though - it's the member selection operator.

Comment: @Leif Andersen: You can google around for C operator precedence; here's the table on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence

Comment: Hmm...okay, thanks.  But the member selection operator is still the operator used to get a particular variable from a struct, yes?  (I always called that the dot operator, or possibly dot product, even though the latter could be confused with vectors in mathematics), thanks for making me aware of the notation.

Comment: @Leif:  Yes, it is used to get a particular variable from a struct.  It's acceptable to call it the "dot operator," but it _cannot_ be called the "dot product operator."

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you're missing: `&em->vdata` is the same as `&(em->vdata)`, not `(&em)->vdata`. That is, it's the address of the `vdata` member of the structure pointed to by `em`. This should be clear if you look at the type of `em` - it's a pointer.

Yes, you can always rewrite `a_ptr->member` as `(*a_ptr).member`, but why bother? That's the point of the syntactic sugar.

Answer (score -1):

"If that's the case, what is the point of passing in &(*a), as a parameter, and not just a?"

Usually none.  But notice that your sample code doesn't compare &(*a) and a.  Your sample code compares &(*a) and b, where b is offset from a by whatever the distance is from the start of em to em's vdata member.